# dbeaver connection to remote postgresql database times out

Tags: postgresql, connection-timeout, dbeaver

When I try to connect to a remote Postgresql database with Dbeaver the connection times out. I can connect to the same database on the same remote machine with psql. I can connect to a local database on localhost.

Where should I look for the problem?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 1):

This is the way i came up with:

1. Open new script file, this script file will only be used for keeping connection alive
2. Execute any query, for example: select now() in this script file
3. Next in bottom left corner click Refresh and set refresh interval, for example, 300 seconds (5 minutes)
4. So above query will be executed every 5 minutes and will keep connection alive

Comment: This Guy must take the best answer. You save my time for manual refresh thank you bro

Answer (score 0):

Could be many reasons why your connection time's out:

1. Your network currently might not have access to the database. / port.
2. Your remote Postgres server is not configured for remote access from your location / user. Go check the Postgres documentation about network configuration OR
   Your could try to use port forwarding with `ssh. -L PORTLOCAL:localhost:POSTGRESPORT postgresserver` and then use `localhost:portlocal` to connect to your remote Postgres server through a tunnel. Lookup ssh port forwarding.
3. You manged to get a connection but the connection was randomly lost /  My solution Was to:  enable Keep-Alive. in the connection settings.
4. disable the option to show all databases in the connection setting. sometimes this prevented me to connection to remote databases.

Answer (score 0):

*This is not the complete solution but it may help narrow your search.*

First try to ping the remote server from your local machine and check if it pings or says request timed out.
If it says "request timed out.", then there is an issue connecting to the host itself and nothing wrong with the dbeaver or postgreSQL.